# Loading up value from SharedPreferences

Tags: android, variables, global-variables, sharedpreferences

In my Application class, I have the following:

```
public void loadPrefs(){
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);  
Boolean soundValue = sharedPrefs.getBoolean("SOUND", false);    
}

public void savePrefs(String key, boolean value){

SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
Editor edit = sharedPrefs.edit();       
    edit.putBoolean(key, value);            
edit.commit();                          

}
```

All OK there as far as I can tell.

Now in my main class which extends SurfaceView, I have the following:

```
myApp mySettings = (myApp)getContext().getApplicationContext();
```

Then I can save values like so: (Again from my surfaceView activity)

```
myPlanSettings.savePrefs("SOUND", false);}
```

However, what I just cannot work out is how to read the value back so I can set a local variable like so:

```
Boolean thisValue = (the value from the shared preferences).
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
public Object loadPrefs(String key,String defaul){
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);  
return  sharedPrefs.get(key,default);
}
```

Cast it with the type while using getting the value

Basic usage:

```
boolean b=(Boolean)loadPrefs("value","default value")
```

Comment: This is generic method you can use for all types of data types don't create each one for the specific type..Create generalised one

Comment: Thanks, I only have 2 Booleans to save so I used something similar to this but didn't use the cast.  Tested and all working :-)